# have issue with token in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, token

my problem is that I get the token from the backend and I set it to local storage but when the user logs into the account data won't show to the user. but when the user refreshes the page, data would show to the user.
what do you think is the problem?
thank you for your time!

```
    const dashboardHeader = async () => {
    await axios.get('adminPanel/dashboard', {
        params: {
            fromDate: 'notSet',
            toDate: 'notSet'
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        setHeaderData(res?.data?.result?.header)
        setLoading(false)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

this is one of my api examples

Comment: please share some code for us to be able to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: my problem was that the page has to refresh after the token is set.

Answer (score 1):

the page has to refresh after the token is set.